# I have overlapping buttons in HTML5

Tags: html, css, button, overlap, overlapping

I have two buttons, one on the left, and one on the right. For some reason when I zoom in, I see my main button, and a bigger one behind it. They both change color when I hover, and are both clickable, but only the main one at the front links me where I want to go. I want the mysterious appearing button behind the main one to disappear. I think it may have something to do with the width, but it is set at 180px, and the height is auto.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="setupstylesheet.css">
        <title>Setting up Your Website Folders</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <img src="Images/web-development-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="400">
            <h1 class="webheading">Website Developement</h1>
            <div class="margin">
                <div class="shading">
                    <h1>2. Setting Up Your Website Folders</h1>
                    <p>In order to have a website, you need to have it set our in a specific way, but make it easy to navigate. This is how you set up your website folders and files:</p>
                    <ol>
                        <li> Create a folder on your hard drive or a USB called "Website".</li>
                        <li>Open a blank Notepad++ document.</li>
                        <li>Save the blank document in your "Website" folder with the name "Index", and a file extension of ".html".</li>
                        <li>Open another blank Notepad++ document and call it "StyleSheet" with the file extension of ".css". Save it in your "Website: folder as well.</li>
                        <li>Inside your "Website" folder, create another folder called "Images".</li>
                        <li>If you wish to include music on your website, create another folder in your "Website" folder called "Audio".</li>
                    </ol>
                    <p>Your website folder should now look something like this:</p>
                    <img src="Images/webfolderdemo.jpg" width="80%" height="80%">
                    <p>Remember whenever you add pictures, put them in the "Images" folder, and music or other audio, put in the "Audio" folder."
                    <div class="needs">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <button type="button" class="needs">1. Things you need</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extrainfo">
                        <a href="extrainfo.html">
                            <button type="button" class="extrainfo">3. Extra Information</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#body {
    background: url(Images/bigimage.jpg);
    background-color:#000000;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.webheading {
    size: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFF00;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

.needs {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    border: 2px solid #FFFF00;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 180px;
}

.needs:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.extrainfo {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    border: 2px solid #FFFF00;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 180px;
}

.extrainfo:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.margin {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
 }

.shading {
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you should have the same class on your buttons and their container. It will apply css on both elements.

Comment: I agree with @j-printemps, by the looks of things the you can probably achieve your expected result by simplifying your markup; moving the `needs` class to the `a` and removing the `div` and `button` elements entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your buttons are 'floating'. you should not have the same class on the `button` and container as mentioned above in the comments.

Once you have your `button`/`div` class situation fixed, you can use `clear: both;` on the containers and/or `display: block`; or `display: block-inline;` and that should stop the buttons from overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="setupstylesheet.css">
        <title>Setting up Your Website Folders</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <img src="Images/web-development-banner.jpg" width="100%" height="400">
            <h1 class="webheading">Website Developement</h1>
            <div class="margin">
                <div class="shading">
                    <h1>2. Setting Up Your Website Folders</h1>
                    <p>In order to have a website, you need to have it set our in a specific way, but make it easy to navigate. This is how you set up your website folders and files:</p>
                    <ol>
                        <li> Create a folder on your hard drive or a USB called "Website".</li>
                        <li>Open a blank Notepad++ document.</li>
                        <li>Save the blank document in your "Website" folder with the name "Index", and a file extension of ".html".</li>
                        <li>Open another blank Notepad++ document and call it "StyleSheet" with the file extension of ".css". Save it in your "Website: folder as well.</li>
                        <li>Inside your "Website" folder, create another folder called "Images".</li>
                        <li>If you wish to include music on your website, create another folder in your "Website" folder called "Audio".</li>
                    </ol>
                    <p>Your website folder should now look something like this:</p>
                    <img src="Images/webfolderdemo.jpg" width="80%" height="80%">
                    <p>Remember whenever you add pictures, put them in the "Images" folder, and music or other audio, put in the "Audio" folder."
                    <div class="button-wrap">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <button type="button" class="needs">1. Things you need</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-wrap">
                        <a href="extrainfo.html">
                            <button type="button" class="extrainfo">3. Extra Information</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css -->

```
.button-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 171px;
}
```

remove float:right from .extrainfo 
removed width for both buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your markup like that :

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="index.html" class="button needs">
    1. Things you need
  </a>
  <a href="extrainfo.html" class="button extrainfo">
    3. Extra Information
  </a>
</div>
```

And CSS could be something like that :

```
    .container {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .button_test {
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
      border: 2px solid #FFFF00;
      background-color: #00FF00;
      border-radius: 10px;
      height: auto;
      width: 180px;
    }

    .button_test.extrainfo {
      // CSS for .extrainfo
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you change the "float" attribute in the class that binds onto the buttons, the buttons would not be overlapping anymore.

If i am not mistaken, you can keep your "float" if you add "padding " attribute to your buttons

Answer (score 0):

OK. I fixed it.

I stupidly had the same class name for my divs and my buttons, so thats why it was doubling up. I also found a much easier solution for aligning my buttons on the same row as eachother. Rather than having a div around each button, I did this instead:

HTML:

```
<div>
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <button type="button" class="needs">1. Things you need</button>
                        </a>
                        <a href="extrainfo.html">
                            <button type="button" class="extrainfo">3. Extra Information</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

As for the CSS, nothing needed to be changed:

```
.needs {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    border: 2px solid #FFFF00;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 180px;
}

.needs:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.extrainfo {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    border: 2px solid #FFFF00;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 180px;
}

.extrainfo:hover {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```